# OpenERP (Odoo) V9 and mobile framework

Tags: android, odoo

I am creating a **mobile app** that uses **Odoo**. When a user enters his details in the form, all the data are saved in the **database**. The same data should be available in the localhost. There should be a **two-way** between the mobile app and the localhost.

Are there any opportunities to connect the mobile framework to the localhost of Odoo (V9) database.

Answer (score 1):

Please click Following link if you are interested in Mobile Framework Development 
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1311831077/learn-5-best-mobile-development-frameworks

This Tutorial Consist of Following things-
Tentative Projects

There are 25 different projects that are included within the course. These projects are divided into categories, with 5 projects for each mobile framework.

**Ionic**

1. Feed Reader - A complete Ionic App to learn how to integrate feed from popular websites.
2. ToDo List - A app to help you learn the core concepts of Ionic
3. Auth0 Login App - A very powerful app whose code can be reused across other apps.
4. Business Finder - A business search App which will help you learn complex concepts of Ionic App development.
5. Meal Tracker - A dietary app which will help you learn the complete lifecycle of Mobile App development in Ionic.

**PhoneGap**

1. Photo Gallery - Learn the basics of PhoneGap by building an Image based application.
2. Workout Tracker - A fitness app to help you master native phone features using PhoneGap.
3. Contact Manager - A complete professional app to help you learn how to access phone specific features.
4. Memo Recorder - A business app which can be modified and developed to create a unique app.
5. Geolocation App - Learn to use location APIs to create more powerful geolocation based apps.

**React Native**

1. GitHub DevSearch - A simple app to help you master the core concepts of React Native.
2. Google Books App - Build a professional app using JavaScript and React APIs.
3. Custom Web Browser - A powerful app to help you use the powerful react library and components.
4. Messaging App - Dive deep into core concepts and React library constructs to build a messaging App.
5. Project Manager - Create a handy tool for managing work and life projects.

**JQM**

1. Mobile Website - Quickly master jQuery concepts  by building a Mobile App.
2. Event Manager - Learn to create a powerful event manager app with mobile Jquery.
3. Movie Listings - Build a movie listing App and learn how to interact with APIs.
4. WikiFind - Learn advanced concepts by creating a Wiki based App.
5. Weather Report - Learn to use Weather APIs in your App.

**Meteor**

1. Idea Manager - Learn the powerful Meteor framework by build a Idea manager mobile App.
2. Magic 8 Ball - A fun app to learn MeteorJS concepts.
3. Spotify App - Build a complex spotify clone app from scratch.
4. Real Estate App - Learn to build an API based app using Meteor.
5. Class Scheduler - Learn to build a scheduling application using Meteor

Comment: Good effort, but the question was actually only about odoo with phonegap